# Detect combination of user input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an alert popup when I press a sequence of keys on my website, for example if I write "420" on my keyboard I want a message to popup saying "You made it" or something. I get it when I use only 2 keypresses using this:

```
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 90) {
    alert("Sweet");
  }
});
```

Which is the CTRL-key + letter Z, but I cant seem to understand how to make it work if I want it to be the correct sequence of 4 2 0 or something similar. And I'm only allowed to use JavaScript.

Comment: If there's a reason the other answer is better, you should really pick that then. I just would like to understand why. To "reward" a *good* answer you can upvote it.

Comment: That was not the intention, I used yours and it worked great and as intended. I just thought I could "mark" two as working answers. I can't upvote yet, since I'm a new member. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that to work, you need to keep track of keys pressed.

Here, I add every key pressed to a variable `str` at that variable's end, and then cut off everything except the last 3 characters.

```js
let str = '';

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  str = `${str}${event.key}`.substr(-3);
  if (str === '420') console.log('You made it!');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simultaneous keys (like ctrl+Z) is different to a sequence (like 420).

One of many strategies could be to split the sequence into an array and use a copy of it (`temp`) to [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) that sequence when the first element is typed.

```js
let targetSequence = "420".split("")
let temp = [...targetSequence]

document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

  if (temp[0] == e.key) {
    temp.shift()
  } else {
    temp = [...targetSequence]
  }
  console.log(temp)

  // If the sequence was done
  if (!temp.length) {
    console.log("--- You did it! ---")
    temp = [...targetSequence]
  }

})
```

```html
<input id="test">
```